# Numpy: arr[...,0,:] works. But how do I store the data contained in the slice command (..., 0, :)?

Tags: python, indexing, numpy, slice

In Numpy (and Python in general, I suppose), how does one store a slice-index, such as (...,0,:), in order to pass it around and apply it to various arrays? It would be nice to, say, be able to pass a slice-index to and from functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python creates special objects out of the slice syntax, but only inside the square brackets for indexing. You can either create those objects by hand (in this case, `(...,0,:)` is `(Ellipsis, 0, slice(None, None, None))`, or you can create a little helper object:

```
class ExtendedSliceMaker(object):
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return idx

>>> ExtendedSliceMaker()[...,0,:]
(Ellipsis, 0, slice(None, None, None))
```

Comment: This directly solves the problem, assuming you don't actually care about the representation or what it means because you're just going to pass it around to use in Numpy. I had the same thought basically, but showed how to dig in and figure out what everything is :)

Answer (score 6):

Use s_ in NumPy:

```
In [1]: np.s_[...,0,:]
Out[1]: (Ellipsis, 0, slice(None, None, None))
```

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent to `(...,0,:)` should be...

```
>>> myslice = (..., 0, slice(None, None))
>>> myslice
(Ellipsis, 0, slice(None, None, None))
```

Comment: No, it's not `slice(0)`; the `0` is just an index.

Answer (score 3):

The neat thing about Python is that you can actually make a class to inspect how these things are represented. Python uses the magic method `__getitem__` to handle indexing operations, so we'll make a class that overloads this to show us what was passed in, instantiate the class, and "index in" to the instance:

```
class foo:
  def __getitem__(self, index): print index

foo()[...,0,:]
```

And our result is:

```
(Ellipsis, 0, slice(None, None, None))
```

`Ellipsis` and `slice` are builtins,  and we can read their documentation:

```
help(Ellipsis)
help(slice)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to just do myslice = slice(1,2) to for example define a slice that will return the 2nd element (i.e. myarray[myslice] == myarray[1:2])