# Store Slice Index as Object

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, nested

Say I have a list of lists of lists etc... of some depth:

```
ExampleNestedObject = numpy.ones(shape = (3,3,3,3,3))
```

In general I can get an element by writing:

```
#Let:
#a, b, c, d, e -> are integers

print ExampleNestedObject[a][b][c][d][e]

#numpy also happens to allow:

print ExampleNestedObject[(a,b,c,d,e)]

#python in general allows:

print ExampleNestedObject[a,b,:,d,e]
```

My question is -> how can I store the index "a,b,:,d,e"  as an object?

```
SomeSliceChoice = a,b,:,d,e

print ExampleNestedObject[SomeSliceChoice]
```

Comment: I see a numpy specific version of this question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795657/numpy-arr-0-works-but-how-do-i-store-the-data-contained-in-the-slice-co?rq=1

Though I am still interested in a generic python solution

Comment: numpy arrays are not lists.

Comment: That solution is generic.

Comment: turns out this solution is not generic to nested python objects. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64419760

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick is to think of an index object as a tuple of slice objects.

Example1:

```
Object[1,2,:] == Object[(1,2,slice(None,None,None))]
```

Example2:

```
WantedSliceObject = (1,2,slice(None,None,None), 4,5)
Object[1,2,:,4,5] == Object[WantedSliceObject]
```

Note the syntax of '''slice:

```
#slice(start, stop[, step])

#1 ==  slice(1, 2, 1)

WantedSliceObject2 = (
   slice(1, 2, 1),
   slice(2, 2, 1),
   slice(None,None,None), 
   slice(4, 2, 1),
   slice(5, 2, 1)
   )

#WantedSliceObject2 == WantedSliceObject
```