# Access jsonable nested object with comma separated key

Tags: python, json, object, indexing, key

First lets create a nested object which is jsonable in python:

```
ExampleObject1 = [ {'a':0, 'b':1} ,  {'c':2, 'd':3} ]
ExampleObject2 = [ {'a':0, 'b':ExampleObject1}, {'c':2, 'd':3} ]
ExampleObject3 = [ {'a':0, 'b':ExampleObject1}, {'c':ExampleObject2, 'd':3} ]
```

We can easily access an element with chaining square brackets like so:

```
print ( ExampleObject3[0]['b'][0]['b'] )

>>> 1
```

How can I access the same element with a list of keys instead of needing the square brackets?

```
print ( ExampleObject3[ (0,'b',0,'b') ] )

>>> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

**Note:** I *can* access `numpy` `array`s this way.
As soon as I try to access a dictionary with comma separated key's then things break.

See: [Store Slice Index as Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40393226/355230).

**Reason:** I just want to be able to pass around an arbitrary key which can be used to go get data later from some large object sitting in memory.

**Edit:** It would also be nice to be able to *change* values in the original object using the key:

```
ExampleObject3[ (0,'b',0,'b') ] = 'alpha'
```

Comment: Numpy arrays override `__getitem__` to allow this syntax. `list` does not work that way.

Comment: There has got to be some other way to carry around the key to access a general object

Comment: I should also add - that it would be most useful if I can modify the original object later with the key. ExampleObject3[ (0,'b',0,'b') ] = 123   or some other new value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't index directly with a list of key like this, but you could make a simple function to do it for you. [`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) is handy for this:

```
from functools import reduce

def fromKeyList(obj, key_list):
    return reduce(lambda o, k: o[k], key_list, obj)

ExampleObject1 = [ {'a':0, 'b':1} ,  {'c':2, 'd':3} ]
ExampleObject2 = [ {'a':0, 'b':ExampleObject1} ,  {'c':2, 'd':3} ]
ExampleObject3 = [ {'a':0, 'b':ExampleObject1} ,  {'c':ExampleObject2, 'd':3} ]

fromKeyList(ExampleObject3, (0,'b',0,'b'))
# 1
fromKeyList(ExampleObject3, (1,'c',0,'b',1, 'c'))
# 2
```

**Edit based on further information**

To *set* an item, you can get all but the last item from the key list, then use the last key to set the item. That might look something like:

```
def setFromKeyList(obj, key_list, val):
    last = reduce(lambda o, k: o[k], key_list[:-1], obj)
    last[key_list[-1]] = val

fromKeyList(ExampleObject3, (0,'b',0,'b'))
# 1

setFromKeyList(ExampleObject3, (0,'b',0,'b'), 10)

fromKeyList(ExampleObject3, (0,'b',0,'b'))
#10
```

Comment: This is great if the data is "read-only" but how do I overwrite the data at key location using this?

Comment: Well…that's the kind of detail that's helpful to have in the question if it's important. See the edit for one approach.

Comment: Yup - fair point -> question further clarified. (I assumed "access" meant both "get" and "set" but I see the ambiguity now)